# Как скопировать один вектор в другой, если у них разные типы? С++

Tags: c++, конструктор, вектор

Предположим, есть вектор:

```
std::vector<MyType1> vec1;
```

При условии, что MyType2 может быть построен из MyType1, как мне инициализировать второй вектор? Пробовал сделать так:

```
std::vector<MyType2> vec2 {vec1};
```

Comment: а не получится ли "каша " с неизвестным состояний объектов?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну у вас получается каша, если вы используете конструктор, принимающий в качестве аргумента другой класс?)

Comment: это не одно и то же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign работает хорошо, если есть подходящее преобразование, которым компилятор может воспользоваться. Если же у него это не получается, то можно сделать вот так

```
std::vector<int> a {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<std::string> b;

std::transform(
    a.begin(), a.end(), // исходный вектор
    std::back_inserter(b), // результирующий вектор
    [](auto q) { return std::to_string(q) + "\n";} // функция преобразования
);
```

я использовал `back_inserter`, который в данном случае просто скрывает `push_back`, но можно выделить память под результирующий вектор (через `b.resize(a.size());` ) и потом можно просто указать `b.begin()`

Comment: Сюда бы еще `b.reserve(a.size());`.

Comment: Тут нужно в пофайлер смотреть, может это микрооптимизация.

Comment: Я сейчас смотрю документацию transform и Assign подходят, но неужели нет метода, похожего на assign, только позволяющего перемещать, а не копировать? Или это делается как раз с помощью transform?

Comment: То есть перемещать? У Вас же разные типы

Comment: @KoVadim я имел ввиду, преобразовывать их в rvalue. Это типы, которые могут быть конвертированы друг в друга. Например vector и класс, содержащий vector с конструктором из vector'a. Если есть конструктор перемещения из vector'а, то как им в таком случае воспользоваться, если assign использует оператор копирования

Comment: видимо имеется ввиду такое `struct Data
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    Data(std::vector<int>&& x) : a{std::move(x)} {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3};
    Data d{std::move(arr)};
}`

Comment: Уж очень как-то непросто... :)

Comment: возможно, Вы не до конца объяснили свою проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
vec2.assign(vec1.begin(),vec1.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

`::std::vector<MyType2> vec2{vec1.begin(), vec1.end()};`